# How to get base64 encoding the same for AutoIt and PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, encoding, base64, autoit

I use [Ward's AutoIt Machine Code Algorithm Collection](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/121985-autoit-machine-code-algorithm-collection/) to get base64 encoding of a string in AutoIt:

```
#Include "Base64.au3"

Dim $Encode = _Base64Encode("ps")
MsgBox(0, 'Base64 Encode Data', $Encode)
```

The result:

```
cHM=
```

PowerShell code to get the base64 encoding of the same string "ps":

```
$commands = 'ps'
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($commands)
$encodedString = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
$encodedString
```

What I got is:

```
cABzAA==
```

The result from PowerShell is what I want. How to get the same result using AutoIt? I guess this is a character encoding issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I ran this script:

```
#Include "Base64.au3"

$Decode = _Base64Decode("cABzAA==")
ConsoleWrite($Decode & @CRLF)
```

I get the result: 0x70007300. Basically, this means there is a '70' character (p), a '00' character (nul), a '73' character (s), '00' character. You can easily recreate this behavior in AutoIt with a function like this:

```
#Include "Base64.au3"

Dim $Encode = _Base64WEncode("ps")
ConsoleWrite($Encode & @CRLF)

Func _Base64WEncode($string)
    Local $result = ""
    Local $arr = StringSplit($string, "")
    For $i = 1 To UBound($arr) - 1
        $result &= $arr[$i] & Chr(0)
    Next
    $result = _Base64Encode($result)
    Return $result
EndFunc
```

The result is: cABzAA==

Somewhat hack-ish, but I'd say it is preferred over full Unicode encoding if that's not what you will ever need.

Comment: TL;DR version:  PowerShell is UCS16LE (UTF16) by virtue of being .NET, so it is encoding as double byte by default.

Answer (score 2):

```
#Include "Base64.au3"    
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
#include <StringConstants.au3>

Dim $Encode = _Base64Encode(StringToBinary("ps", $SB_UTF16LE))
MsgBox(0, 'Base64 Encode Data', $Encode)
```

This will give what you want :

```
cABzAA==
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ASCII encoding instead of Unicode:

```
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($commands)
```

Comment: Hi MrKWatkins, to me, the result from PowerShell is correct. I need this result from AutoIt. So I can't change the PowerShell code.

Comment: Ah, sorry, misread. Don't know about AutoIt, however does it have a method for base 64 encoding bytes instead of a string? In which case you could manually convert the string to bytes using Unicode encoding yourself and pass that in.